# Can't access the tomcat 9 administrator on localhost:8080/admin to add the tomcat users

Tags: tomcat9

I would like to add the tomcat 9  users from front end using localhost:8080/admin(Tomcat9 administrator) and it is not available on tomcat 9.I can only access the manager and host manager and they do not have the  functionality to add the tomcat users(config/tomcat-users.xml) from the tomcat 9 front end.But i used to use the same URL on tomcat 5(Tomcat 5 administrator) to add the tomcat users.Is there anyway to add the tomcat users from fronted using tomcat9.

Thanks

Comment: if you still have access to your old tomcat installation, try to copy the admin webapp over to the tomcat9 webapp folder, and restart. I haven't tried this but it just might work.

Comment: I tried and i get below error  
FAIL - Application at context path [/admin] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin]]]

Comment: share the whole snippet in question. Also could you please confirm are you using zip installation?

Comment: I can able to access the admin after i copied the tomcat 5 admin to tomcat 9 and i have to add the missing libraries to fix the issue.Now i can login to admin but when i try to click on users i get javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: MBeanServer is not available error.

Comment: I think it will save you a lot of headaches to simply edit the text file `Tomcat 9.0\conf\tomcat-users.xml` using a text editor.

Comment: Yes told the same to my client but they want the users and roles to be maintained from front end.